# How does Whatsapp iOS Backup works? Double space required avoidable

Tags: ios, icloud, backup

**WhatsApp is an odd and inconvenient outlier since (compared to iCloud Photo library) it literally duplicates the space required if both switches are on, let me explain:**

There are 2 Whatsapp backup switches to handle, they are both **on** by default:

**1st switch:** iPhone Settings app > Tap your name in the top > iCloud > scroll down to see the switch (this switch creates a live backup that allows for an independent backup, meaning you don't need to restore your whole iphone to restore this backup, you can delete Whatsapp Only and said backup will be detected when you reinstall Whatsapp). You get to pick your frequency on inside-WhatsApp settings section.

**2nd switch:** iPhone Settings app > Tap your name in the top > iCloud > Manage Storage > click "Backup" green icon row > Click your device > here you have a list of your TOTAL apps, each might save a tiny bit of settings info for each app (not the app itself), **this is a packaged backup that also saves your device settings, home screen app order, wallpaper, etc, even the downloaded app list (no matter if you switch off every app)**. **So, Here you see WhatsApp too (2nd switch) <- if on too, Whatsapp backup will take 2x space of your total iCloud space.** given the first switch is also on. As I understand, this backup can only be accessed if you restore the whole iPhone (whole package see).

**Post-context:**

For years, I've turned off the 2nd switch with no problems. **But ever since iOS 13, background activity is a mess for Whatsapp**, **and even though I have more than enough space (more than 2x, and with one switch off) auto-daily Whatsapp backup is not happening on the 1st switch** I now have the question if I can invert the switches, and still be able to access WhatsApp backup by only deleting and reinstalling the whatsApp app, not restoring the whole iPhone. This question arises since the packaged backup (2nd switch) for the rest of the apps (including WhatsApp) works flawlessly, daily, perfectly fine... and at least I could be in peace about the saved info.

But the obvious best solution, is for things to work as before (1st switch on only). It literally broke with iOS 13, and hasn't been fixed up until now. This even looks sketchy to me (you know, doubling space required = more people paying for iCloud space, why doesnt it work like Photo Library? If both switches ok, it only uploads once)

***Does anyone have a suggestion?***

TIP: Yes. It doesn't matter if you have iCloud Photo library on on both sections, Apple is smart about this and only backcups once (only takes space one time), **that's why I say WhatsApp is an inconvenient-odd outlier when it comes to both switches management.**

Comment: Have you contacted WhatsApp support about this issue?

Comment: Not sure I understand assessment of switches. "Switch 1" is about WhatsApp using iCloud to store the data it uses, "Switch 2" is about apps/app data to be included in an iPhone backup. What kind of suggestions (besides "raise a bug report") would you expect to get here?

Comment: I have contacted WhatsApp numerous times since iOS 13 release (and several others for other reasons before that) and they've always been the worse customer service I know; they answer nonsensical copy/pasted text (after their automated bot response that is) It always a dead end. What other suggestions? maybe someone can 1st confirm I understand the switches, and then due to their personal experience tell me how they solved this. Don't be rude, its obvious that said possible solution wouldn't occur tu me since: I still have the issue and I'm asking if there's one that I don't know of.